# wiimote WallTime problem

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm not capable of running the wiimote_node.py by using a very simple launch file:

```
<launch>
 <!-- joy node -->
   <node respawn="true" pkg="wiimote"  type="wiimote_node.py" name="wii" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

I get the following error:

```
process[turtle_wii-1]: started with pid [8703]
Press buttons 1 and 2 together to pair (within 6 seconds).
    (If no blinking lights, press power button for ~3 seconds.)
No Bluetooth interface found
[FATAL] [WallTime: 1301480233.413341] No Wiimote found to pair with.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/joystick_drivers/wiimote/nodes/wiimote_node.py", line 1201, in <module>
    rospy.rospy.loginfo("Exiting Wiimote node.")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rospy'
[turtle_wii-1] process has died [pid 8703, exit code 1].
```

However it works when doing:

```
$ rosrun wiimote wiimote_node.py
```

It looks like an issue with the rospy WallTime

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9604/wiimote-walltime-problem/) by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2011-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on 2011-04-01**:
Thank you very much for solving this so fast!

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-03-31**:
here is the ticket I opened for myself: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4892

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-03-31**:
okay the I fixed the AttributeError but that is unrelated to the pairing.. your launch file should work I just tested it with a wiimote and everything seems to be working. I'll push out a minor release update today for joystick drivers.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-03-31**:
it looks like it's a bug let me look at the code.. .it looks like it's calling the method rospy.rospy.loginfo which isn't valid. I'll check it out and most likely put out a minor release update.

**Comment by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on 2011-03-30**:
I forgot it, thank you, I have updated the question.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-30**:
Could you post the smallest launch file that produces this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bug solved: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4892

---

Originally posted by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) with karma: 202 on 2011-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1